# Number of unique IDs and sum of values per category in a large dataset

Tags: vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, powerquery

I have a large dataset (approx. 250.000 records) where I have an ID column, different categories an ID can belong to and a value column:

[image: ex]

Now I want to calculate the unique occurences of each ID per each category and same for the sum of the value. The result for the example should look like this:

[image: so]

In the example I was able to do this manually. However, I have a large dataset and I cannot do this manually. I thought about it in different ways, but I did not find a good solution for this. One way would be to do it for each single cell with the PowerQuery Editor and then enter the desired number for each cell (this is the way I used to create the solution for the example). But then I have to do this manually with PowerQuery for each cell. Also doing all the work with usual Excel formulas for each single cell is not a good solution, as it includes a lot of manual work. And I would like to avoid doing it manually and thought there must be a better way. If there is an Excel solution I am happy with it. If it is necessary to use VBA I am also ok with it.

Comment: @braX I did so. As I said I tried to do it manually with PowerQuery. This is the way I created the example solution. However, this is not a good approach to tackle this problem with a large dataset. This is my question.

Comment: I would try helping you, if I would understand what exactly you want accomplishing... In the existing situation picture, i can see IDs, which should be unique, like 1000, 1001, 1002 etc. Where are they in the desired situation? How do you count CatA, CatB etc.? Just incrementing in case of YES? Even in this way, what the new table represnts, in terms of CatA, CatB etc., which now appears on the rows, too? Then, the values should be accumulated of the same YES cases, for each ID? Can you better describe **in words** what is to be done to the range you intend to process?

Comment: Still alive? Do you really need help?

Comment: How does your  output make sense? Why arent the columns of the sample output ID#?  If you are just trying to count ID by group, then click select ID and Value, unpivot other columns, group, then pivot the results